# header function php won't redirect using post request

Tags: php, function, post, header

so I have index.html I'm sending a url as hidden input to post.php
method is post
but I can't redirect using header function using post. for example

```
<?php $redirect = $_POST['link']; header("location: ".$redirect."");?>
```

Comment: Why can't you?  What specifically happens and how does this fail?  What values are being posted to the server?  How are you posting those values?  What is the `location` header returned?  Please provide debugging information about the problem.

Comment: it doesn't shows anything it dies.

Comment: no error nothing

Comment: index.html sends http://example.com to post.php as a hidden input and in post.php $redirect recieves the url and header function doesn't redirect using the variable $redirect

Comment: Then now is the time to start doing some debugging.  For example... How are you posting data to the server and what data is being posted?  In the response from the server, what is the `location` header?  Don't just describe what you assume the code *should* be doing, provide a more complete example and include observed debugging information of what is *is* doing.

Comment: I'm sending  a url from index.html as a hidden input using post request  as I described and I recieve the post request in post.php as $redirect = $_POST['link'];  then I try to redirect it to this $redirect variable because it is recieving the url  header("location: ".$redirect.""); ?>

Comment: Take a step back and consider what you're asking... You are currently asking this community to take your word for it and assume that any other code you've written *must* be infallible and that PHP's `header` function *must* be fundamentally broken.  I'm afraid that's unanswerable.  The `header` function itself is not broken.  It does exactly what it's written to do.  Somewhere in the code you've written there is likely a mistaken assumption, possibly a typo, or something that's wrong.  But unless you can provide an actual example demonstrating the problem we can't find what's wrong.

Comment: For tips and information on how to write a question, you are encouraged to read [ask] and its linked resources.